# Sidebar to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering how to get the **color** of my sidebar all the way to the bottom of the page and not have **any** white space between the sidebar and the bottom of the page.

What I see in Firefox is:

[image: What I see in Firefox]

What I see in Chrome:

[image: What I see in Chrome]

[Here's the link to my web page](http://redsky.incredifull.com)
And here's part of my CSS:

```
/* Sidebar */
#sidebar {
    height: 100%;
width: 318px;
float: left;
position: absolute;
padding: 20px 0 0 0;
background-color: #e7d9c9;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url('/imgs/map.png');
}

#sidebar h1 {
padding: 0 0 20px 0;
margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #62879e;
}

.sidetext {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #62879e;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
}

.sidelink ul {
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidelink li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidelink li a {
    display:block;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    font-size:16px;
    color: #62879e;
    text-decoration:none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #62879e;
            padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.sidelink li a:hover {
    border-left:14px solid #1e416f;
    color: #1e416f;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- SIDEBAR -->
<div id="sidebar">
<h1>Caul / Cbua</h1>
<div class="sidetext">
    Duis aute irure dolor in rep-rehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor eu fugiat nulla pariatur. fugiat nulla pariatur.
</div>

<h1>Commit</h1>
<div class="sidelink">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Am I missing something? It already appears to do what you're asking for.

Comment: I just took a look and what you're describing is how it behaves in Chrome. Also - you don't need float with position:absolute.

Comment: I see about 20px of space in between the sidebar and the bottom of the page. I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: @FrontEndGuy It's floating left of the content area.

Comment: I dont really think anybody has actually understood what you really want. I think what you want is the all the text from the sidebar to touch the bottom and the map to be seen clearly! Is that what you want?

Comment: If we look at the sidebar, we can see that the background is only upto second Lorem ipsum and there is no background beyond it. That is what she wants as per my understanding.

Comment: @MarsOne I want all of the color of the sidebar (you can actually see what I mean in the link provided..) to touch the bottom of the page with no white space at the bottom while having the map exactly where it is. It's a background color and background image.

Comment: @MichaelaLeBlanc, has this issue been resolved? bcos i see the same thing in chrome and ff

Comment: @MarsOne No, Because all I've really done now is set the sidebar's bottom padding so that it goes down more and that's not correct. Still back to square one without it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#sidebar {
    background: url("/imgs/map.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 #E7D9C9;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
    width: 318px;
}
```

Change the style for sidebar to the above style.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I don't think so, if you look at the sidebar, you can see that the background is only upto second Lorem ipsum and there is no background beyond it. That is what she wants as per my understanding.

Comment: This is strange, I checked in IE 10, 9, Fox 22, as well as chrome, works for me..

Comment: @MichaelaLeBlanc Please change the style for #sidebar as I have provided and check whether that is your requirement or not.

Comment: @Mr.Alien If it is like what I have said, then it is not working fine for me in Mozilla.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham I've done so and no improvement. You can check so live here: http://redsky.incredifull.com/

Comment: @MichaelaLeBlanc Sorry, my understanding on your question was wrong. Will improve my answer and let you know.